# how to change user account when oozie submit job to hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, oozie

When I am running a shell script using oozie, I noticed that in yarn log, "user.name=yarn", So it causes permission problems,how can I switch account to my hadoop account when oozie submit the job to yarn?

Answer (score 1):

Am not sure about what do you mean by **user.name=yarn**, is the log reflecting the username for job oozie job ???
What is reflecting in the oozie UI or by executing the Job Info in the conole.
oozie job -oozie http://localhost:8080/oozie -info 14-20090525161321-oozie-joe
Output should be like

```
Workflow Name :  map-reduce-wf
App Path      :  hdfs://localhost:9000/user/joe/workflows/map-reduce
Status        :  SUCCEEDED
Run           :  0
User          :  joe
Group         :  users
Created       :  2009-05-26 05:01 +0000
Started       :  2009-05-26 05:01 +0000
Ended         :  2009-05-26 05:01 +0000
Actions
.----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Action Name             Type        Status     Transition  External Id            External Status  Error Code    Start                   End
.----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
hadoop1                 map-reduce  OK         end         job_200904281535_0254  SUCCEEDED        -             2009-05-26 05:01 +0000  2009-05-26 05:01 +0000
```

normally Oozie start jobs with the User which being used to execute the start command.

These should not create any permission issue if You update the core-site.xml by passing parameter as 
The superuser must be configured on namenode and jobtracker to be allowed to impersonate another user. Following configurations are required.

```
     <property>
       <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.groups</name>
       <value>group1,group2</value>
       <description>Allow the superuser oozie to impersonate any members of the group group1 and group2</description>
     </property>
     <property>
       <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.hosts</name>
       <value>host1,host2</value>
       <description>The superuser can connect only from host1 and host2 to impersonate a user</description>
     </property>
```

If these configurations are not present, impersonation will not be allowed and connection will fail.

If more lax security is preferred, the wildcard value ***star*** may be used to allow impersonation from any host or of any user.

Answer (score 0):

You can change user with Oozie option `-doas`:

```
-doas <arg>           doAs user, impersonates as the specified user
```

[Impersonation, doAs](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.1/DG_CommandLineTool.html)

> The -doas option allows the current user to impersonate other users
> when interacting with the Oozie system. The current user must be
> configured as a proxyuser in the Oozie system. The proxyuser
> configuration may restrict from which hosts a user may impersonate
> users, as well as users of which groups can be impersonated.